# Can't connect CSGO-Server or SSH on my Ubuntu 16.10 VM

Tags: virtualization, 16.10, network-bridge, sshd, nat

I've installed Ubuntu on Orcale VM VirtualBox.

The internet connection is over NAT. I've tried to set it to Bridged Adapter, but then I don't have any access to internet on Ubuntu.

I've installed srcds (Counter strike global offensive dedicated server). The Server is running but I can't connect to server either locally or from public.

It seems that I have internet connection, but I cannot connect to public.

I have SSH installed. I have checked via http://canyouseeme.org/ but its says

```
"Reason: Connection refused".
```

How do I allow connections to see my service and how do I connect to the service?

Comment: Well, you won't be able to connect to it outside your LAN unless you do some port forwarding on your router